# Bootstrap 4.3.1 the styling is lost on small screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4.3.1 the styling is lost on small screens. This was not a problem with 4.2.1. At width 576px and smaller the divider-strip coding is plain text with no bottom border. The custom css is:

```
.divider-strip {
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px #607d8b solid;
}

.divider-strip h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.strip-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #607d8b;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
}

.block-title {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="divider-strip block-title">
  <h4>Accordion 1</h4><span class="strip-block"></span></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tryied use media tag?

Comment: I am not versed in how to add a media tag. Would you be so kind as to explain or lead me to an example? Thank you.

Comment: Yes... I will post an answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media tag in css is used to allow you configure your style based on the device screen size. For example:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

When the screen be small than 200px the body will be `lightblue`, when is bigger then 200px the body will be red. Look at this exemple in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t6Lj372/1/). You can look at almost every screen device [here](https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488), there is a code with comments end almost every css rule.

You also can use `!important` to override the bootstrap css rules, this command forces the css uses your code, for example:

```
body {
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

To learn more about `!important` take a look [here](https://www.developeracademy.io/blog/css-important-rule-use-correctly/)